# Formatting onset terminus data for dynamic network visualisation

Tags: r, animation, sna, statnet

I am looking at how government agencies change over time. The plan is to use the ndtv package to visualise changes. However, I am running into problems and have no idea what I am doing wrong! I suspect my data is not formatted correctly.

I have an nodelist that lists vertex ids, agency name, node onset and node terminus:

```
nodelist <- read.csv("https://github.com/aterhorst/data/raw/master/edgelist.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and an edgelist showing onset, terminus of edges:

```
edgelist <- read.csv("https://github.com/aterhorst/data/raw/master/edgelist.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I can create a network object pretty easily:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sna)
nw <- network(edgelist %>% select(head, tail),
              vertex_attr = nodelist %>% select(vertex.id, agency),
              vertex.attrnames = c("vertex.id", "agency"),
              directed = F)
print(nw)
plot(nw)
```

Now I want to make a dynamic network object:

```
library(tsna)
library(ndtv)
dn <- networkDynamic(nw, 
                     edge.spells = edgelist,
                     vertex.spells = nodelist)
```

Then the wheels fall off:

```
Error in networkDynamic(nw, edge.spells = edgelist, vertex.spells = nodelist) : 
  vertex.spells requires the vertex.id column to be numeric
```

I tried changing onset, terminus from integer to numeric - makes no difference. I have tried different ways to create the dynamic network object e.g.

```
dn <- networkDynamic(edge.spells = edgelist)
```

This produces this error:

```
Initializing base.net of size 2020 imputed from maximum vertex id in edge records
Error in activate.edges(base.net, onset = edge.data[, 1], terminus = edge.data[,  : 
  Onset times must precede terminus times in activate.edges.
```

and:

```
dn <- networkDynamic(edge.spells = edgelist, vertex.spells = nodelist)
```

gives me this error:

```
Error in networkDynamic(edge.spells = edgelist, vertex.spells = nodelist) : 
  vertex.spells requires the vertex.id column to be numeric
```

I played around with the order of the edge.spell and this yielded a positive result:

```
 dn <- networkDynamic(net, 
                      edge.spells = edgelist %>% select(onset, terminus, tail, head))

Edge activity in base.net was ignored
Created net.obs.period to describe network
 Network observation period info:
  Number of observation spells: 1 
  Maximal time range observed: 2014 until 2020 
  Temporal mode: continuous 
  Time unit: unknown 
  Suggested time increment: NA
```

All good. Now when I add vertex.spell I get this error:

```
dynamicNet <- networkDynamic(net, 
                         edge.spells = edgelist %>% select(onset, terminus, tail, head), 
                         vertex.spells = nodelist %>% select(onset, terminus, vertex.id) %>% 
                         mutate(vertex.id = as.numeric(vertex.id)))

Error in networkDynamic(net, edge.spells = edgelist %>% select(onset,  : 
  vertex.spells requires the vertex.id column to be numeric
```

Which is bizarre as I have explicitly stated vertex.id to be numeric! Obviously, I am stuffing up with formatting somewhere but its not obvious where. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you need to first create the static network (tho that should work). The main problem seems to just be the column ordering in the lists. The help file `?networkDynamic`  indicates that it requires a specific order for the `edge.spells` and `vertex.spells`:

> `edge.spells` "... Assumed to be [onset,terminus,tail vertex.id, head vertex.id]. ..."
>
> `vertex.spells` "...Assumed to be [onset,terminus,vertex.id]"

Your data looks like:

```
> head(nodelist)
  vertex.id                                  agency onset terminus
1         1                             AAF Company  2014     2020
2         2              Aboriginal Hostels Limited  2014     2020
3         3         Administrative Appeals Tribunal  2014     2020
4         4 Aged Care Quality and Safety Commission  2014     2020
5         5                   Airservices Australia  2014     2020
6         6  Albury-Wodonga Development Corporation  2014     2020
> head(edgelist)
  head tail onset terminus
1   10    3  2014     2020
2   10   11  2014     2020
3   10   12  2014     2020
4   10   18  2014     2020
5   10   22  2014     2020
6   10   23  2014     2020
```

So if the cols of your data are re-orderd..

```
nd <-networkDynamic(edge.spells = edgelist[,c(3,4,2,1)],
  vertex.spells=nodelist[,c(3,4,1)])

Initializing base.net of size 217 imputed from maximum vertex id in edge records
Created net.obs.period to describe network
 Network observation period info:
  Number of observation spells: 1 
  Maximal time range observed: 2014 until 2020 
  Temporal mode: continuous 
  Time unit: unknown 
  Suggested time increment: NA
```

This creates network object and dynamics.  Since it looks like your `nodelist` has only one row per vertex, labels can be brought in with

```
network.vertex.names(nd)<-nodelist$agency
```

Comment: I found library(tidyr) interfered with ndtv. Using base R terminology works best with ndtv.

Comment: The tidyverse creates tibbles so we need to convert using as.data.frame()